# TS - Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Allure'

Tags: typescript, cypress, allure

When attempting to label steps within my Cypress test using https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin, I have the following code:

```
  cy.allure().startStep('Step 1').then(() => {
    cy.visit('/path1/path2');
  });
  cy.allure().endStep();
```

however, the `.then(() => {})` is causing a TS error:

> [ts] Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Allure'.

My tsconfig.json (I tried appending /reporter to the cypress-allure-plugin line as shown in https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin-example/blob/master/cypress/tsconfig.json but that didn't work):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "..",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "@testing-library/cypress",
      "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.then()` is implied, since Cypress runs on a command queue.

Just sequence the commands like this

```js
cy.allure().startStep('Step 1')
cy.visit('/path1/path2');
cy.allure().endStep();
```

See example from the repo

```js
describe('Cypress commands steps', () => {
    it('should produce allure steps for cypress chainer commands', () => {
        cy.log('before command');
        cy.allure().startStep('step before "this is custom"');
        cy.thisiscustom('customname').then(() => {
            cy.allure().testName('new name');
        });
        cy.allure().endStep();
        cy.allure()
            .startStep('step nested 1')
            .startStep('step nested 2')
            .startStep('step nested 3');
        cy.request('https://google.com.ua')
            .should('have.property', 'status')
            .should('be.eq', 200)
            .and('be.not.eq', 400);
        cy.allure().endStep().endStep();

        cy.wrap([1, 2, 3])
            .then((array) => array[0])
            .as('firstItem')
            .should('be.eq', 1);
        cy.allure().endStep();

        cy.allure().step('step parent 1');
        cy.get('@firstItem').then((item) => {
            cy.log(item);
        });

        cy.allure().step('step parent 2');
        cy.request('https://google.com').then((res) => {
            cy.log(res);
        });
        cy.log('after command');
    });
})
```